# MAR Assumption missing data

Tags: r, missing-data, mice

I want to do predictions of missing data MAR. I do the simulations by generating normal data with 1 y and some x. after that I remove the data: Proportion of missing value from 5%, 10% to 50%. I use imputation mice. I would to ask, how much imputation should I do for each of the missing data proportions. I have not found literature about it. I just get the MCAR, the amount of imputation is as much as a lot of missing data.

Answer (score 1):

If you are wondering how many records to impute per imputation sample, then the answer would be as many as there would have been without missing data. If the question is on the number of imputed datasets then the answer is more is better. Just a few (3-5 is often quouted) may be enough to achieve coverage probabilities at or usually above the nominal level etc., but with more you get higher efficiency (narrower CIs, more power) and less dependence of the results of the random number seed. Unless it's computationally a problem, I normally like 1000 or more imputed datasets for the types off problems I work on (for which simulation studies suggest 250 are often good and 1000 a tiny not better and the computational cost of going to 1000 is pretty negligible). With a lot of missingness (50% is certainly a lot), you may want to go even higher, if feasible.

Comment: I read in the literature "Multiple imputation using chained equations: Issues and guidance for practice" written by white et al, 2010. They said that for MCAR, the number of imputations will be equal to the number of missing data. Could you give me the literature for the MAR mecanism as you said above? thank you

Comment: Imputed records or imputed complete datasets?

Comment: I work now with incomplete datasets, not complete datasets.

Comment: Not sure how you mean, I took that as a given. What number are you worrying about?

Comment: I search the literature which say how many the number of imputation (m) in mice algorithm for MAR mecanism. is that the same with MCAR mecanism that the number of imputation (m) is be equal to the number of missing data. for example, I do simulate the proportion of missing data 40% in my datasets, and I use m =40 for the method MICE. and now I have not found teh literature that how many the number imputation (m) for mice algorithm in MAR mecanism.

Comment: X% = X imputations is a bad idea even for MCAR and certainly for MAR. This is an article with a MAR setting that looked at this a bit: http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/pst.1705

Comment: it is interesting article, but now I work in MICE.

Comment: So what? Multiple imputation is multiple imputation (plus minus minor details) irrespective of software.